# Generating additional entries in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, equations

I suspect it might be easy question but I have never used LaTeX before and I struggle with even finding something on that topic. I've got the document that is full of equations (~230 in total) titled with `textbf`. So an example of single "entry" is:

```
\textbf {Small-Angle Formulae (in radians)}
\begin{equation}
\sin(\theta) \approx \tan(\theta) = \theta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\cos(\theta) \approx 1 \approx 1 - \frac {\theta^2} {2}
\end{equation}
```

The document has sections that are included in ToC but there is nothing more in it. I'm wondering whether there is a way to include all the titles of equations in the ToC (from the above entry example I'd like to have `Small-Angle Formulae (in radians)` in ToC with either page number or equations numbers) without modifying all 200 entries (although I could use "search and replace" feature of course).

Could you please help me here?

Comment: For future reference: If you had `\newcommand{\equationtitle}{\textbf}` in your preamble and used `\equationtitle{Small-Angle Formulae (in radians)}` in your text, it would be far easier to manage than using a search-and-replace functionality.

Comment: That's a good tip, thank you! Although in that case the document is not mine, just shared with me. And I am trying to modify it a little bit for my needs.

Comment: @Werner I have taken your comment and used it to extend my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard LaTeX macro `\addcontentsline{<file>}{<kind>}{<title>}`.

```
% addtotocprob2.tex  SE 23115

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}

Some initial words.

%\end{document}

\textbf {Small-Angle Formulae (in radians)}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Small-Angle Formulae (in radians}
\begin{equation}
\sin(\theta) \approx \tan(\theta) = \theta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\cos(\theta) \approx 1 \approx 1 - \frac {\theta^2} {2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

See the `tocloft` package manual for more information on `\addcontentsline` and friends.

**EXTENDED ANSWER (15 January 2022)**

Following from @Werner 's comment I have added his thought to my original answer.

```
% addtotocprob2.tex  (revised 15 Jan 2022) SE 23115 

\documentclass{article}

%% added 15 Jan 2022
%% based on Werner's comment plus putting the title into the ToC
\newcommand{\equationtitle}[1]{\textbf{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}  

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}

Some initial words.

%\textbf {Small-Angle Formulae (in radians)}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Small-Angle Formulae (in radians)}
\equationtitle{Small-Angle Formulae (in radians)}
\begin{equation}
\sin(\theta) \approx \tan(\theta) = \theta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\cos(\theta) \approx 1 \approx 1 - \frac {\theta^2} {2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]